# Periodic Airdrops on Solana

Tags: solana-program, spl-token

What is best practice for running Airdrops periodically? For example Airdrop daily rewards to holders of a certain token? Is something like this even possible to do while just using an on-chain program?

Answer (score 1):

you can write a script to do that depending on the language you are using, if you are using javascript then you can use web3.js on solana to [get started](https://solanacookbook.com/references/local-development.html#subscribing-to-events)

just use the devnet and program a timer thread to airdrop you at intervals..

from 0xmukesh answer:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

// 0 * * * * means every 1 hour - https://cronexpressiontogo.com/every-1-hour
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', function(){
  // Establish new connect to devnet - websocket client connected to devnet will also be registered here
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// Create a test wallet to listen to
const wallet = Keypair.generate();

// Register a callback to listen to the wallet (ws subscription)
connection.onAccountChange(
  wallet.publicKey(),
  (updatedAccountInfo, context) =>
    console.log("Updated account info: ", updatedAccountInfo),
  "confirmed"
);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. See my comment on 0xmukesh's answer, but I'm wondering primarily about best practice. So let's say I have token A, and want to airdrop a certain amount to some accounts every 1 hour. Do I understand you correctly that I would run an external script that would perform this airdrop? Is there a better way perhaps? Perhaps there is an event for a particular Solana tick.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Node.js, then you can use libraries such as [`node-schedule`](https://npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to schedule a job which would run periodically at a certain interval.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

// 0 * * * * means every 1 hour - https://cronexpressiontogo.com/every-1-hour
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', function(){
  // add the function which would airdrop tokens over here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how you would set up something to run periodically (you could use a cron job as well). But I was wondering what was best practice and I gather from your answer it's an external script that invokes the instruction?

Comment: Oh! So you want to periodically airdrop the tokens under an on-chain program? If so, then you can take a look at [Clockwork](https://www.clockwork.xyz/). They have an example for your use-case in their repository - https://github.com/clockwork-xyz/examples/tree/main/payments. Here is a list of all the examples - https://docs.clockwork.xyz/developers/examples